# NextJS 13 Hydration failed error, when using Modal Component

Tags: modal-dialog, react-bootstrap, next.js13, hydration

Hello I am using the SRC folder with APP router nextjs 13 and trying to set up simple Modal message, which is visualized correctly, but throws the following Error in the Console:

*Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .*

I've tried to put the modal in different places, in the layout.tsx, in provider, in page, as a component, or directly in the page, with wrapping div and <></> but with no luck. I guess this has something to do with the fact that when I inspect the code, the code of the modal is always just after the body tag, and not where the component code is positioned.

layout.tsx

```
...

return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="min-h-screen">
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
        {/* Allow more height for mobile menu on mobile */}
        <div className="h-40 md:hidden" />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
```

page.jsx

```
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
export default function Home() {
 return (
    <>
      <SomeComponents/>
<Modal show={true}>Text</Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have tried with clean skeleton nextjs13 with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use useEffect for setting state true, dont set true directly.
here is a sample code.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

interface PopupProps {
    item: any
}
function Popup({ item }: PopupProps) {

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setShow(true);  // <---- 
      }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}
                size='lg'
                centered
                className={`old-modal`}
                keyboard={true}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you are reading this text in a modal! 
                </Modal.Body>
            
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Popup;
```

Comment: Hi, well this works too, I am not sure which solution would be more efficient but this one seems a little more understandable (natural). But if someone has the same issue I would recommend checking the Shodipo Ayomide's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem once before, the error you're seeing typically happens when the markup that the client tries to render during hydration differs from what the server renders.

You can use dynamic imports with the `ssr: false` option to fix this,

You can read more about **Dynamic imports and code splitting with Next.js** [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/dynamic-imports-code-splitting-next-js/)

Comment: Thank you very much. If somebody needs the exact code for the inport: import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const NameOfCompontn = dynamic(() => import(path-to-component ), {
  ssr: false,
});